# Changing the area of a pixel search

Tags: vb.net

I have been working on an app to search for 3 pixels in a certain area then play a sound.  It currently works however I wish to reduce the zone of which it searches from the whole screen to a rectangular area on my screen, this is to save memory usage of the app, here's the code that works

```
Private Sub dcdTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dcdTimer.Tick
    Dim screensize As Size = New Size(My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width, My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height)
    Dim screenshot As New Bitmap(My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width, My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height)
    Dim ge As System.Drawing.Graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
    Dim pointx As Integer = 1
    Dim pointy As Integer = 1

    ge.CopyFromScreen(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, 0), screensize)
    looking = True



    Try
        While looking = True

            Dim atpoint As Color = screenshot.GetPixel(pointx, pointy)
            Dim reckcol1 As Color = Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b)      'first pixel colour
            Dim reckcol2 As Color = Color.FromArgb(a1, r1, g1, b1) 'second pixel colour
            Dim reckcol3 As Color = Color.FromArgb(a2, r2, g2, b2) 'third pixel colour

            If atpoint = reckcol1 Then  'Matches 3 pixels
                Dim testPoint As Color = screenshot.GetPixel(pointx, pointy + 10)
                If testPoint = reckcol2 Then
                    Dim testPoint2 As Color = screenshot.GetPixel(pointx + 10, pointy + 10)
                    If testPoint2 = reckcol3 Then

                        My.Computer.Audio.Play(sounddir + "Found.wav")
                        looking = False
                        Sleep(15000)
                        pointx = 0
                        pointy = 0
                    End If
                End If
            End If

            pointy = pointy + 1

            If pointy = My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height Then
                pointy = 0
                pointx = pointx + 1

            End If
        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

I tried to use this code as suggested:

```
    Dim pointofY As New Point(500, 400)
    Dim screensize As New Size(400, 200)
    Dim screenshot As New Rectangle(pointofY, screensize)

    Dim ge As System.Drawing.Graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
```

However, using a rectangle does not allow me to use getpixel or use ge.copyfromscreen

Comment: Provide a rectangle representing the area you want instead of using screen.bounds. Outside of that this feels more like a do-it-for-me

Comment: It's not a do-it-for-me at all, the code is written, I want to know how to create the rectangle to represent the area rather than using screen.bounds

Comment: `Dim myRectangle as new Rectangle(pointx, pointy,width,height)` calculate the points and width/height based on what portion of the screen... if you just want to represent a form perhaps, you could grab it from `Form.Bounds`